# Invoking an Objective-C method by name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, reflection, runtime

How can I invoke a method at runtime on an Objective-C class when all I have is it's signature in string form:

```
NSString* typeName = @"Widgets";
NSString* methodName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"add%@Object:", typeName];
```

Note that the method name can change at runtime but the number of arguments stays fixed - one in this instance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(methodName);
[myObject performSelector:selector];
```

There are also `performSelector:withObject:`, and `performSelector:withObject:withObject:` methods if you need to pass parameters.

Comment: Don't forget about NSInvocation for when you need more than 2 parameters.

Comment: If you use `performSelector:withObject:`, be sure to end your method name with a colon.  The method name without a colon matches a method with no parameters.

Comment: Thanks [dreamlax](http://stackoverflow.com/users/10320/dreamlax)!. Here a [complete answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/313455/1121497) about `NSInvocation`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to perform methods invocation in reflection on objetive c just use this quick recipe. objC enabling us checking if an object supports a particular interface at runtime, This invocation happens dynamically if exists.

```
Class classAPI = NSClassFromString(@"yourClassName");
SEL methodToPerformSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"yourMethodName:");
NSMethodSignature *methodSignature = [classAPI methodSignatureForSelector:methodToPerformSelector];
NSInvocation *myInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:methodSignature];
[myInvocation setTarget:classAPI];
[myInvocation setSelector:methodToPerformSelector]

/* if you have an argument */
[myInvocation setArgument:&someArgumentToAddToYourMethod atIndex:argumentIndexInMethod];
[myInvocation retainArguments];

[myInvocation invoke];
```