# Objective-C:Method name changes with different actions

Tags: objective-c

There is a requirement, I need to call method from other class, but the method name is changed with different actions, something like below:

```
NSArray *arrays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa", @"bbb", nil];
for ( NSString *array in arrays ){
blablabla.......
Aclass *abc = [[Aclass alloc] methodName%@:variable],array;
blablabla.......
}
```

Is there any way to write code like that in Objective-C?

Thanks!

more info:
the method name in Aclass is like:

```
-(NSArray *)procWithAAA:(NSInteger)aaaID
```

Thanks!

the method name in Aclass is like:

-(NSArray *)procWithAAA:(NSInteger)aaaID

---------as you guys's suggestion, i write code like below, but it doesn't work-------

```
NSArray *arrays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa", @"bbb", nil];
for ( NSString *array in arrays ){

SEL customSelector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"procWith%@", array]);

if ([Sync respondsToSelector:customSelector]) {
                        Aclass * abc = [Aclass performSelector:customSelector:aaaID];
                    }else {
                        NSLog(@"## Class does not respond to %@", customSelector);
                    }
```

Aclass * abc = [Aclass performSelector:customSelector:aaaID]; this part is not allows in objective-C.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[self performSelector:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#>];`

```
 NSArray *selectorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc",@"gcd", nil];

for (NSString *method in selectorArray) 
{
     [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(method) withObject:nil];
}
```

Method with parameters,

```
NSArray *selectorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc:",@"gcd:", nil];

for (NSString *method in selectorArray) 
{
     [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(method) withObject:@"test"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

the method name in Aclass is like:

-(NSArray *)procWithAAA:(NSInteger)aaaID

NSArray *arrays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa", @"bbb", nil];
for ( NSString *array in arrays ){

SEL customSelector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"procWith%@", array]);

if ([Sync respondsToSelector:customSelector]) {
                        Aclass * abc = [Aclass performSelector:customSelector:aaaID];
                    }else {
                        NSLog(@"## Class does not respond to %@", customSelector);
                    }
It doesn't work.

Comment: Ok.Instead of returning a value you can store in a class level property and access it. I mean you can modify the method to make it return void. I will look for some alternative.

Comment: You should use NSInvocation.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313400/nsinvocation-for-dummies

Answer (score 1):

Use [`NSSelectorFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString) to convert a string into a `SEL`, then [`-[NSObject performSelector:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector%3a) or [`NSInvocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003671) to call the method.

Or, if you can, use [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NSSelectorFromString` function.

```
SEL customSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"selectorName");
if ([class respondsToSelector:customSelector]) {
    [class performSelector:customSelector];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"## Class %@ does not respond to %@", class, customSelector);
}
```

More information about selectors can be found in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocSelectors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH23-SW4).