# How to pass 3 parameters to @selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I created an action in

```
-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

which just like this:

```
self.moveAction = [CCSequence actions:                          
                   [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:moveDuration position:touchLocation],
                   [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(guyMoveEnded)],
                   nil
                  ];
```

but now, I want to auto-invoke a following method by `@selector`:

```
-(void)guyMoveEnded:(BOOL)flag AndWhere:(CGPoint)where Andtime:(float)time{
    //do something...
}
```

How can I do it?
Please help me, I'm confused about the selector.

Thanx!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add your parameters to a `NSArray` and then give it as the argument to your selector:

```
NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a str", [NSNumber numberWithInt:42],myObj];
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:)withObject:params];
```

And then unpack the arguments in your method:

```
-(void)myMethode:(NSArray*)params
{
    NSString *strArg = [params objectAtIndex:0];
    NSNumber * numVal = [params objectAtIndex:1];
    NSObject *objArg = [params objectAtIndex:2];
    int intArg = [numVal intValue];
    .
    .
    .   
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest way, the harder way involves NSInvocation.  +1

Comment: I think your code uses `numVal` and then `intVal`... They are supposed to be the same var, right?

Answer (score 3):

[Apple suggests](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:withObject:) using [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) when you need to pass more than 2 arguments. 
Here's a very good example: [NSInvocation for Dummies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313400/nsinvocation-for-dummies#313455)

A short synopsis from that answer with no explanations:

```
// Prepare the object
NSMethodSignature * mySignature = [NSMutableArray 
    instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(addObject:)];
NSInvocation * myInvocation = [NSInvocation
    invocationWithMethodSignature:mySignature];

// Set selector and object
[myInvocation setTarget:myArray];
[myInvocation setSelector:@selector(addObject:)];

// Set arguments
[myInvocation setArgument:&myString atIndex:2];

// Invoke it
[myInvocation invoke];
```

It is a lot more code than just calling a selector with `performSelector:`, but allows you to call methods with any number of arguments. This is especially useful if you can't change the signature to decrease argument count, as Cipramill suggests.

Comment: @coverback I think you mean "with more than TWO parameters" OR "with 3 parameters OR MORE"

Comment: ...unles there's a `-performSelector:withObject:withObject:withObject:` that I'm not aware of :)

Comment: Yeath,apple advice if you post more than 2 parameters you should better use NSInvocation

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a NSDictionary object with your Parameters & pass that Dictionary to your selector & you can get the values inside your method from Dictionary. following is for reference:

```
 "NSDictionary *dictionary = nil;
  BOOL flag = YES;
  CGFloat time;
  CGPoint pt;
 [dictionary setValue:flag forKey:FIRSTPARAM];
  [dictionary setValue:time forKey:SECONDPARAM];
  [dictionary setObject:point forKey:THIRDPARAM];
[self performSelector:@selector(methodName:) withObject:dictionary];

"
```

Either You can create your custom class for that Pass the object of that class.

Comment: your answer is the most detailed ,thanks so much,i'll try it.

Comment: In my opinion, using a dictionary is better than an array because each object can be 'named' meaningfully (by its key). Of course, you could use an `enum` with meaningful names for the indices of the array...

Answer (score -1):

```
[favProductCell.btnAddtoCart addTarget:self action:@selector(arrayForAddToCart:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[favProductCell.btnAddtoCart setTag:indexPath.row];

-(void)arrayForAddToCart:(id)sender
{
    if (![self.addToCartProductIdArray containsObject:self.favoriteProductArray[[sender tag]]])
        [self.addToCartProductIdArray addObject:self.favoriteProductArray[[sender tag]]];
}
```