# How may I run this code?

Tags: ios, boolean, uitextview

I need to run this set of code:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
```

in another method (IBAction).

So for example I need to run it like this :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

How may I do that?

Comment: NSInvocation is probably you best option. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313400/nsinvocation-for-dummies/3224774#3224774

Comment: Why are you wanting to call the UITextView delegate directly?  Do you have the range of edited text and replacement text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant pass arguments to perform selector.

You need to encapsulate the data you want to send along into some single Objective C object (e.g. a NSArray, a NSDictionary, some custom Objective C type) and then pass it through the[NSObject performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]. For your case:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
```

Something like:

```
NSArray * arrayOfThingsIWantToPassAlong = 
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects: range, text, nil];

[self performSelector:@selector(fooFirstInput:) 
           withObject:arrayOfThingsIWantToPassAlong  
           afterDelay:15.0];
```