# Create object with reflection

Tags: objective-c, reflection

I have a class where I need to create an Object from using reflection.

say I have the following class (got by class-dump or else):

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
    - (void)dealloc;
    - (id)initWithArguments:(char *)value1 arg2:(int)value2;
}
```

Now I want to create a new object from it using reflection:

```
Class theClass = [instance class];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"initWithArguments:arg2:");
id newInstanceOfClass = [[theClass alloc] performSelector:selector withObject:????];
```

How can I pass the secondary parameter?

Note that I am not able to change the layout of `SomeClass`.

Comment: But you have a header file for the class? So the class definition is visible to your code?

Comment: Nope, I have no header.

Comment: Note that performSelector:withObject: expects an *object* as argument, so that would not work with a `char *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `performSelector:withObject:withObject:` method if you are going to pass 2 parameters. If you need to pass more than two the best way is create custom class which will hold all of your parameters and pass the class with `performSelector:withObject`: method. You cannot pass primitive variable so replace int with NSNumber.

//EXTENDED

If you want to pass more than 2 parameter and you cannot amend the method to accept custom object you can use NSInvocation:

```
// List of yours parameters
NSString *s1 = @"parameter 1";
NSString *s2 = @"parameter 2";
NSString *s3 = @"parameter 3";

// your selector
SEL selector = @selector(testParam1:param2:param3:);

if([self respondsToSelector:selector]) { // just to make sure there is right method to run,
// you have to change it to [theClass alloc] respond to selector instead of self
    NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector:selector]];
    [inv setSelector:selector];
    [inv setTarget:self]; // change it to the object you want to call the parameter (theClass)

    [inv setArgument:&s1 atIndex:2]; //arguments 0 and 1 are reserved for self and cmd you have to start passing your parameters with index 2
    [inv setArgument:&s2 atIndex:3];
    [inv setArgument:&s3 atIndex:4];
    [inv invoke];
}
```

Comment: and if there are more then 2 paremeters?

Comment: See my answer. If there is more that two you can create custom method and pass it as a parameter. I can show test code if you like.

Comment: The problem is that I am not able to change the class I want to call, so passing multiple parameters as one object does not work.

Comment: @MartinR I haven't seen the other answer because I was writing this one. This is working example so maybe Eun will use it.

Comment: @Greg: Then I apologize. I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Create a header for the class and import it. Use the header to interact with the class (so you won't be making any `performSelector...` calls).

If for some reason you can't do that, use `NSInvocation` instead of `performSelector...`.

Comment: You were faster :-) - Here are some NSInvocation examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313400/nsinvocation-for-dummies.

Comment: could you make an example for my case?

Comment: The question linked by @MartinR has a number of good examples that you can learn from. The process is the same for pointer variables and primitive variables.