# Why NSInvocation

Tags: ios, nsinvocation

Why use NSInvocation when you could just call the method? Need to ask this question because I can't understand the need to use this class. What is the advantage of using it over just calling the method like below.

```
 [myArray addObject:myString];
```

**Additional info:**
What specific challenges does it resolve/address which can't be addressed by the other method calling options.

Comment: when you don't know what to call at compile time. i.e. unknown selector, unknown number of arguments, unknown return type.

Comment: why would I not know? I should know the methods of a class first hand when I develop right? Perhaps there is something else when you say there are unknowns...would appreciate an example scenario. tnx

Comment: there are a few Ruby/Python/Javascript/Lua to ObjC binding frameworks. you can call method using scripting language, which you won't know anything in compile time

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSInvocation for Dummies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313400/nsinvocation-for-dummies)

Comment: that or the answers here are not yet answering my questions so it would not be a duplicate. Of course I read that post already.

Answer (score 3):

One use: You could use it to implement a chain of undo actions - where each different action would be a different method call to undo. You would encapsulate each undo action as a method call wrapped in an NSInvocation object.