# What is forward invocation? What it is supposed to do? Why it is ever used?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I came across this code in a project, where it is using `NSInvocation`. I want to know what it is supposed to do, and why would we ever need that. Simple explanations would be appreciated. I am posting the code.

```
// Public interface
@interface CCDelegateSplitter : NSObject

- (void) addDelegate: (id) delegate;
- (void) addDelegates: (NSArray*) delegates;

@end

// Private interface
@interface CCDelegateSplitter ()
@property(strong) NSMutableSet *delegates;
@end

@implementation CCDelegateSplitter

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    _delegates = [NSMutableSet set];
    return self;
}

- (void) addDelegate: (id) delegate
{
    [_delegates addObject:delegate];
}

- (void) addDelegates: (NSArray*) delegates
{
    [_delegates addObjectsFromArray:delegates];
}

- (void) forwardInvocation: (NSInvocation*) invocation
{
    for (id delegate in _delegates) {
        [invocation invokeWithTarget:delegate];
    }
}

- (NSMethodSignature*) methodSignatureForSelector: (SEL) selector
{
    NSMethodSignature *our = [super methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    NSMethodSignature *delegated = [(NSObject *)[_delegates anyObject] methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    return our ? our : delegated;
}

- (BOOL) respondsToSelector: (SEL) selector
{
    return [[_delegates anyObject] respondsToSelector:selector];
}

@end
```

Comment: [Check this answer out.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313400/nsinvocation-for-dummies) Pretty much tells you everything you need to know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the link in bfitch's comment. That covers *what* NSInvocation is, and hints at *why* you would use it, but doesn't cover the *why* in much detail.

`NSInvocation` lets you do fairly advanced things like creating a proxy object that actually forwards messages to another object. With NSInvocation it's possible to take **ANY** message at runtime and forward it to another object.

Another example is the performSelector family of methods. There's `performSelector:`, `performSelector:withObject:`, and `performSelector:withObject:withObject:`. (plus variants like `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, `performSelector:onThread:`, etc.) Those methods take 0, 1, or or 2 objects as parameters. If you need to invoke a method on another object that takes scalar parameters, or anything other than 0, 1 or 2 objects, you're out of luck. However you can send messages with ANY type of parameters using NSInvocation.

Note that when blocks were added to Objective-C the need for tricks like performSelector and NSInvocation become less. Blocks can reference variables from their enclosing scope, which makes them more flexible.

Answer (score 5):

I'll assume you know what an `NSInvocation` is (if not, it's a data structure that holds all the information needed to make a method call; think "blocks" from long before blocks were added to the language).

`forwardInvocation:` is one of the methods that the runtime will call if it cannot find an implementation for a method. So if you pass a `-doSomething` message to an object `[object doSomething]`, it will first check whether it has a `doSomething` method. Then it will check its superclasses. It'll try dynamic method resolution (`resolveInstanceMethod` for instance). It'll look for a forwarding target (`forwardingTargetForSelector:`), and it'll finally, if everything else fails, it'll create an invocation (using `methodSignatureForSelector:` and punt to `forwardInvocation:`. By default, `forwardInvocation:` just calls `doesNotRecognizeSelector:` which crashes you on iOS (or terminates the current thread on OS X). But you can override it to do something else (like they have here).

`methodSignatureForSelector:` is necessary so that the runtime system can create an invocation out of a message. This one either returns a method signature from this object or its superclasses, or it asks one of its targets for the appropriate method signature. A selector by itself isn't enough to figure out exactly how to call a method. The system needs to ask an object how the method actually works (what types it takes and what type it returns).

The code you've posted is a multi-delegate trampoline. It will accept any selector that its targets respond to (technically it'll pick a random target and see if it responds), and it'll forward that message to all of its targets.

For a similar trampoline with some comments about usage, you may want to look at [RNObserverManager](https://github.com/iosptl/ios5ptl/blob/master/ch04/ObserverTrampoline/RNObserverManager.h).

Comment: Good answer, but from the question I assumed that the OP did **not** know what an `NSInvocation` is.