# Returning result of executing a selector on another thread in Swift or Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Suppose I wanted to invoke a selector `calc` on a **specific thread**. Meaning it's the case where I **really must** use a run loop (can't use GCD).

`calc` performs some calculation and produces a result value, suppose an Int.

It is easy to pass a parameter to the selector method.

What would be a good way to retrieve the result value?

```
@objc function calc(val: Any) {
    guard let val = val as? Int else { return }
    let result = val * 10
    ...
}

// ... somewhere in a calling object
let val = 3
perform(#selector(MyClass.calc(val:)), on: myThread, with: val, waitUntilDone: true, modes: [RunLoopMode.commonModes.rawValue])
// ... how to get the result of calc() ?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313400/nsinvocation-for-dummies ? Then performing the invocation on antoher thread is another question, but could be an hint on how pass params, etc.

Comment: @Larme I am not sure NSInvocation works with run loops? Note the requirement from the supplied code that the function is run on a specific (another) thread while the calling thread is suspended (waiting for completion).

Comment: As @Larme mentioned in the comments, I would also suggest using `NSInvocation`. Returning the value from `calc` would be done by a closure thats handed into the `calc` function, like: `@objc func calc(val: Any, calculationFinishedHandler:(result:Int)->()) { ... calculationFinishedHandler(result:result)}` If you need more details (or sample code), I could elaborate it (but will take a while)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how come, you cannot use GCD and have to stick to run loops?

Comment: @DávidPásztor That is due to some esoteric legacy C library code (math stuff) that periodically misbehaves when executed from different threads. Yes, I have tried standard sync methods (mutex, semaphore) but still no stable outcome. It must be a purposefully allocated single thread that is looking after the code. Thus neither GCD nor NSInvocation work here. It's one of those tricky case where one can't go by the book.

Comment: `NSInvocation` has in the actual sense nothing do do with threads. It is just a means to execute a function dynamically - which has been the only way to do so for functions with more than two parameters before blocks / closures were invented. You could then use the `NSInvocation` to execute this on a dedicated thread.